# i want to select entire row by checkbox but gives error "Incorrect integer value: 'meetingID' for column 'meetingID' at row 1"

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

Here I put the checkbox and rest for selecting columns

```
while(rst.next())  
{   
%>  
<tr> 
<td  height="30" bgcolor="#A0A0A0" align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="meetingID" value="meetingID"></font></td>
<td  bgcolor="#a8a8a8" align="center"><font color="#000000" size="2"><%=rst.getString(1)%></font></td>
<td  bgcolor="#b0b0b0" align="center"><font color="#000000" size="2"><%=rst.getString(2)%></font></td>
<td  bgcolor="#b8b8b8" align="center"><font color="#000000" size="2"><%=rst.getString(3)%></font></td>
<td  bgcolor="#c0c0c0" align="center"><font color="#000000" size="2"><%=rst.getString(4)%></font></td>
<td  bgcolor="#c8c8c8" align="center"><font color="#000000" size="2"><%=rst.getString(5)%></font></td>
</tr>  
<%
String select[] = request.getParameterValues("meetingID");  
if (select != null && select.length != 0)  
{
out.println("You have selected: ");  
for (int i = 0; i < select.length; i++)   
{ 
out.println(select[i]);  
}}  
}  
rst.close();  
stmt.close();  
con.close();  
}  
catch(Exception e)  
{  
System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
}  
%>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
```

I want to select entire row by checkbox but gives error "Incorrect integer value: 'meetingID' for column 'meetingID' at row 1"

Comment: Why aren't you using javascript for this if you want the meetingId value? request.getParameter would really only be something you would use if you are submitting a form or going to a new page.

Comment: thanks for reply but didnt get you, plz elaborate

Comment: In order to use `request.getParameterValues()` you need to have a `GET` or `POST` request. It doesn't look like you do at all to me.